# Using rdp remote connection mac, cannot remote into azure vm after mavericks update

Tags: azure

Getting error "Remote Desktop Connection cannot verify the identity of the computer that you want to connect to...."

- I can connect using windows computer so I went to the server from windows and made sure remote access enabled and also the checked the "allow connection running remote desktop..."

Before the update I was able to use it but it was kinda few months back so not sure if the update is the issue or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried the new "Microsoft Remote Desktop" app? https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417

Comment: Thank you Jeff. It worked with the new RDP client.